# Any cross-platform two-panel file manager?

Tags: files, cross-platform

Using a two-panel file manager really helps for some file operations.

Midnight Commander is available for any Linux distribution.  There's Servant Salamander for Windows.   I have also looked at Total Commander.  Mucommander is pretty good, except that it lacks file search (which I require).  Is there any cross-platform file manager that works well on Windows, MacOS, and Ubuntu?

My requirements include:

- File search
- High resolution graphical interface
- Right mouse click menus
- File icons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Midnight Commander has been [ported to Windows](http://www.siegward-jaekel.de/mc-gb.html) and can be [installed on OSX](http://michigantelephone.wordpress.com/2008/03/25/how-to-install-midnight-commander-under-mac-os-x-the-easy-way-using-rudix/). A bit messy, but should get you what you want.

Comment: Midnight commander is good, but it's text-based and don't utilize nowadays high resolution screens, right mouse click, file icons etc.
Windows port is very old :(.

Comment: If these features are requirements, you should probably edit your question to make it clear that you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not available for OS X, but my vote is definately for [Double Commander](http://doublecmd.sourceforge.net/). I've been using it for several months now. It's written in Free Pascal/Lazarus, so you get to skip all that awful Java overhead and interface, and the developers are very responsive to feature requests.

Ehtyar.

Answer (score 0):

[FAR Manager](http://www.farmanager.com) - unfortunatelly, only on Win platform.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, only on Win platforms. For win it's also servant salamander, total commander etc. But interested in cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

In a pinch I've used [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). At least in the Windows version (and I'm assuming its in the Linux and Mac version) on the View menu there is a "2 panel" option. Its not the best, but its gotten me by in an emergency. After re-reading your post a few times I'm not sure it will do what you want.

Since I work in a primarily with Windows I usually use PowerDesk Pro. Way back in version 5 I got a free copy with another program I bought and I've been a paying customer since. :)

Comment: No, 7-Zip has nice GUI only on Windows. For MacOS, Ubuntu, Suse and other unix-like OS'es it just packs and unpacks files, near no GUI.

Comment: Guess that's what I get for assuming...

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking about local <~> remote dirs, [**FireFTP**](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/) is great two panel manager. Has most of the features you require. Being Firefox add-on, it's completely cross-platform. The problem is I don't see how could you use it for local <~> local.

[fireftp http://fireftp.mozdev.org/images/fireftpthumb.jpg](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/images/fireftp.png)

Answer (score 0):

for finding and sync operations beyond compare http://www.scootersoftware.com/ has been a help in the past.  Linux and windows versions.

Comment: It's more a diff tool. Interesting in group copy, move, search in files etc.

Comment: It does diff - but if you haven't checked out the folder comparisons and the ease that you can move items manually or via scripts you may want to give it another look.  Group copy, move searching in files are all available.  YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I got used to [muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com/) on my Mac, but it's also available on Windows, Linux and even as Webstart. It has a nice installer, runs within seconds, supports drag & drop, etc.

However, it doesn't seem to be famous..

Comment: It does not support search

Answer (score 0):

Another free FTP/SFTP with a two-panel interface is [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

Cheers,

Thomas